# Change python environment 'cmd' is not recognized

Tags: python, windows, cmd, anaconda, conda

7 using anaconda on win10. And then I use conda to create a seperate environment of python3:

conda create --name python3 python=3

However, when I use activate python3

it shows that:

```
C:\Users\xxxxx>activate python3
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'cmd' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have checked all the environment:

```
C:\Users\Alex Cui>conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
python3                  C:\Users\Alex Cui\Anaconda2\envs\python3
root                  *  C:\Users\Alex Cui\Anaconda2
```

Can someone help why it cannot recognize activate cmd?

Comment: You are supposed to do conda activate python3

Comment: I tried conda activate but the same: C:\Users\Alex Cui>conda activate python3


CommandNotFoundError: Command Error: error with command 'activate'. Command not found: 'activate'. 'activate' is not a conda command.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure your Environment Variable PATH has the directory where the cmd.exe exsts(C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe).

Right click "computer", select "properties", then "advanced system settings", then "environment variables". Select the User variable PATH and add "C:\Windows\system32;"

Edit: corrected that the PATH just needs the directory containing cmd.exe, not the full path of cmd.exe

Comment: I did what you suggest but still have the same error message. realy weird.

Comment: You don't need to put the EXE file on the PATH, you need to put its directory onto the PATH. Can you try adding `%SystemRoot%\system32` to your PATH?

Comment: @darthbith Yes that is correct, just the directory for it to know where to search.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use spaces in paths where anaconda is installed. Reinstall elsewhere and make sure windows does not search for used commands in a path with spaces too.

Answer (score -1):

Check the [document on conda](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/using/using.html). 
In order to use conda to perform execute commands, conda must be entered in order to indicate that the command is to be executed by conda, as

```
conda activate python3
```

Similar to how you use python via cmd in windows, for example,

```
python setup.py install
```

will tell python to install setup.py.

Comment: I tried conda activate but the same: C:\Users\Alex Cui>conda activate python3 CommandNotFoundError: Command Error: error with command 'activate'. Command not found: 'activate'. 'activate' is not a conda command.

Comment: This is not correct, as indicated by the error message in the comment above by @Alex. The command is simply `activate envname` on Windows.